# Socket.io and Extjs: Retrieving data for Store

Tags: javascript, node.js, extjs, socket.io, store

is there a way for the Extjs Store to get data from Socket.io in a live feed manner? Where there is no polling.

What I found would require polling where I will get the data in json format from a URL using express. I was thinking I then do a setTimeout to do a load for the Store. Like I said polling.

```
var app = express();

app.get('/getnames', function(request, response) {

    response.json({data:[{id:1,name:"John"}, {id:2, name:"James"}]});
});
```

is there any other way than this?

Or any suggestion guys? aside from using setTimeout.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to use longpolling for websocket frameworks. All you need to do, is to listen events and write handlers. For example;

```
var socket = io.connect("localhost:8080");
socket.on("feed", function(data){
    myStore.loadData([data], true);
});
```

When you emit "feed" event from your socket.io server, above code will add the feed data to the store immediately. To emit data on your socket.io server with node.js;

```
io.emit("feed", {"id":123, "msg":"example feed"});
```

Of course, you have to write the logic that when someone(or your app) post a feed, it should emit a message to the server, and the server must emit this to the other clients. This way, all clients have a realtime feed viewer.